# Error converting data type varchar to numeric from my application

Tags: sql-server

Hi i have created a view to calculate the sum col1/ sum col2
however col1 contains predefined values 100,150,45,50,60 and NA. col1's data type is varchar and col2's data type is numeric. I have set a condition on my statement not to perform any calculation if col1 has a value of 'NA' however i keep getting this error from the application side "error converting data type to numeric"

```js
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'ROM_PAD_REPORT') AND XTYPE = 'V')
DROP VIEW ROM_PAD_REPORT
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ROM_PAD_REPORT]  
AS  



SELECT  DISTINCT CAST(NULL AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) AS PK,
        DTS.PK AS PPK,
  A.PROD_BLOCK,        
        A.ELEVATION,
        A.MATERIAL_TYPE,
     A.SAMPLE_COUNT,
     A.QC_SAMPLE_COUNT,
  A.TRUCK_CAPACITY,
  A.CONTENT,
  A.Valuegt AS GRAMS_PER_BLOCK,
  A.DATE_DISPACTHED as DATE_DISPATCHED         
  
FROM ( SELECT  RP.PROD_BLOCK,
     MIN(RP.ELEVATION) AS ELEVATION,
     MAX(RP.MATERIAL_TYPE)AS MATERIAL_TYPE,
     MAX(RP.DATE_DISPACTHED) AS DATE_DISPACTHED,
     SUM(CAST (RP.TRUCK_CAPACITY AS varchar(8))) AS TRUCK_CAPACITY,
     SUM(RP.CONTENT) AS CONTENT,  
     (SUM(CAST(RP.TRUCK_CAPACITY AS varchar(8)))/SUM(RP.CONTENT)) AS Valuegt,
     (SELECT COUNT(DD.SAMPLE_ID) FROM ROM_PAD_DATA DD WHERE DD.PROD_BLOCK = RP.PROD_BLOCK) AS SAMPLE_COUNT,
     (SELECT COUNT(DD.SAMPLE_ID) FROM ROM_PAD_DATA DD WHERE DD.PROD_BLOCK = RP.PROD_BLOCK and DD.SAMPLE_TYPE IN ('STD', 'BLANK')) AS QC_SAMPLE_COUNT
  FROM  ROM_PAD_DATA RP 
  WHERE RP.TRUCK_CAPACITY <> 'NA'
  GROUP BY RP.PROD_BLOCK) A
  
JOIN ROM_PAD_DATA B ON A.PROD_BLOCK = B.PROD_BLOCK
JOIN DATASET DTS ON (B.PPK = DTS.PK) 
JOIN BUS_UNIT BU ON (BU.PK = DTS.PPK)

GO
GRANT SELECT ON ROM_PAD_REPORT TO sableApp
GO
```

Comment: I believe the error resides in `WHERE RP.TRUCK_CAPACITY <> 'NA'`, try replacing this check with `WHERE CAST(RP.TRUCK_CAPACITY AS NVARCHAR) <> 'NA'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `WHERE RP.TRUCK_CAPACITY <> 'NA'` condition with:

`WHERE CAST(RP.TRUCK_CAPACITY AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) <> 'NA'`

Comparison of different datatypes will generate this error, and for this scenario we need to explicitly convert the value in `RP.TRUCK_CAPACITY` to a string.

Comment: @BethuelMhlongo In StackOverflow spirit don't forget to upvote/mark the answer as correct if the solution has worked for you, so that others will know how to resolve this, if they come across the same issue.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `(n)varchar` variables and parameters that you use (including when you use them in a `CAST` or `CONVERT` statement!)

Comment: @marc_s I usually do this, but it slipped this time. Thank you for your comment and for the link.